# Component fails to correctly render on first passes (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to update a React Component (B) that renders an SVG object passed from a parent Component (A).

`B` then uses `getSVGDocument().?getElementById("groupID")` and adds handling for events based on members of the SVG group.

`A` also passes in a prop that indicates mouseover in a separate menu.

Simplified code in B:

```
export function ComponentB(props: {
    overviewSvg: string
    highlightKey?: string
}) {
    function getElems(): HTMLElement[] {
        let innerElems = new Array<HTMLElement>()
        const svgObj: HTMLObjectElement = document.getElementById(
            "my_svg"
        ) as HTMLObjectElement
        if (svgObj) {
            const elemGroup = svgObj.getSVGDocument()?.getElementById("elemGroup")
            if (elemGroup) {
                for (let i = 0; i < elemGroup.children.length; i++) {
                    innerElems.push(elemGroup.children[i] as HTMLElement)
                }
            } 
        } 
        return innerElems
    }
    const elems = getElems() // Also tried variations with useState and useEffect, can't seem to get the right combination...
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("effect called")
        console.log(elems)
        elems?.forEach((elem) => {
            elem.onmousedown = () => toggleColor(elem)
        })
    }, [elems, props.overviewSvg])

    useEffect(() => {
        elems?.forEach((elem) => {
            if (elem.id === props.highlightKey) {
                setActive(elem)
            } else {
                setInactive(elem)
            }
        })
    }, [elems, props.highlightKey, props.overviewSvg])

    return (
        <>
            <object data={props.overviewSvg} id="my_svg" />
        </>
    )
}
```

I'm not sure what the appropriate parameters for the dependencies in useEffect should be, or if this is entirely the wrong approach?

The console shows that on loading, the array of `elems` is often empty, in which case the `onmousedown` loop of course doesn't add any functions.

After the parent sets the props.highlightKey, the second function is triggered and that then triggers the first effect and adds the mousedown functions.

What should I be changing to make the component correctly render before any parent highlightKey changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behaviour by using `useRef` and applying it to the DOM element, then adding an `onload` behaviour to that element.

```
// Get a ref for the <object> element
const svgObj = useRef<HTMLObjectElement>(null)
const [elemArr, setElems] = useState(Array<HTMLElement>())    

if (svgObj.current) {
    svgObj.current.onload = () => {
        const elems = getElems()
        elems.forEach((elem) => {
            elem.onmousedown = () => toggleColor(elem)
        })
        setElems(elems)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    elemArr.forEach((elem) => {
        if (elem.id === props.highlightKey) {
            setActive(elem)
        } else {
            setInactive(elem)
        }
    })
}, [elemArr, props.highlightKey])

return (
    <object ref={svgObj} data={props.overviewSVG} ... />
)
```